# Why aren't Ngrx-Effects subscribed automatically in a inherited generic class

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have the case that I have several effect classes in my project which are extended by a generic class. All effects which are inherited from the generic class aren't subscribed automatically. Instead I have to subscribe manually to the effect/observable in the constructor of the generic class:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class GenericEffects<T extends Action, K> {
     action: T;
     constructor(
       TCreator: { new (): T },
      protected actions: Actions,
      protected store: Store<K>,
      protected route: string

      ) {
       this.action = new TCreator();

       --> this.effect1.subscribe(); <---
    }

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    effect1 = this.actions.ofType(genericActions.EFFECT_1).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select<RouterReducerState>('route')),
      map(([action, routerState]) => routerState.state.url),
      map(url => {
        if (url.indexOf(this.route) !== -1 && url.length === 
          this.route.length + 1) {
        this.store.dispatch(this.action);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

FeatureEffectsModule:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class FeatureEffects extends GenericEffects<
      featureActions.WhatEverAction,
      fromFeature.State
     > {
      constructor(
        actions: Actions,
        store: Store<fromFeature.State>,
        private service: FeatureService
      ) {
        super(
          featureActions.WhatEverAction,
          actions,
          store,
          'foo'
        );
      }
    }
```

**What am I missing or what is the reason I have to do this manually ?**

Comment: without the subscription within the generic class the effects aren't fired... took me a while to recognize this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the effects fire in the non-generic version, I would not consider subscribing in the base class constructor of the generic version. I found that re-declaring the effect in the derived class works, so I accept this amount of code repetition. In your own example, I add 1 line:

```
@Injectable()
export class FeatureEffects extends GenericEffects<
  featureActions.WhatEverAction,
  fromFeature.State
 > {
  constructor(
    actions: Actions,
    store: Store<fromFeature.State>,
    private service: FeatureService
  ) {
    super(
      featureActions.WhatEverAction,
      actions,
      store,
      'foo'
    );
  }

  @Effect()  effect1;      //   <---   like this

}
```